# Client Side Javascript: Is it possible toget the laid out text rendition of an HTML element in the DOM?

Tags: javascript, html, layout

For any HTML element we can easily get it's `outerHTML`, `innerHTML` and `textContent` as properties.

Console based browsers, like [lynx](https://lynx.browser.org/) and [elinks](http://www.elinks.cz/), produce fair approximations of intended HTML layout in text form. I wonder if there's a DOM method or a Javascript library that can offer the same to client-side Javascript.

My main interest is in preserving table layout.

I've search rather extensively on-line for possible solutions, but this alas, is one of those problems that is hard to describe well, or better said I'm not familiar with an established jargon or language that describes the desired task here. The best I can come up with the title of this question "get the laid out rendition of an HTML element".

Comment: `innerText` may get you closer, this is one of the very few times `innerText` may be worth using

Comment: I'm pretty sure there isn't a way to do this. Layout is graphical in GUI browsers, not textual.

Comment: @CertainPerformance, thanks, that is brilliant. I looked and look, and missed that one. But tested it, both inner and outer Text and both are not bad. Much better that textContent. I'd say this is 90% of a full satisfactory solution/answer and if there isn't a better one, you could post it ans an a answer and win my upvote!

I even tested pasting teh text into a spreadsheet and because it's rendered with tab separated columns on tables it pastes tables into spreadsheets beautifully. I'm using this for a copy button on a website. Long story.

Comment: @CertainPerformance, it's not perfect mind. Just tried on a table of tables. That is I have one table each cell of which contains a table. And interestingly each inner table is rendered well (tab separated columns, looks OK in a text editor - depending on tab stops and cell content) and well pasted into a spreadsheet. But tke outer table is linearised. That is, loses its structure. If I have 3 column x 2 rows of  inner tables, outerText on the outer table yields 1 row x 6 columns.

Comment: @Barmar, never say never ... as stated Lynx and Elinks do a pretty fair approximation

Comment: Of course, because that's what they're designed to do. A graphical browser has no need to do plain text layout, and there's no functions to get that from it.

Comment: But you're mistaken. As CertainPerformance pointed out, innerText works fairly well. Why do you think a graphical browser has no need to a plain text layout? It's almost universally useful when you select a pile of stuff on a web page and paste it into a text context (like a text editor). You can get gibberish or something that resembles what you copied. The desire for the latter is fairly understandable not uncommon.

Answer (score 1):

[`innerText`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/innerText) will get you somewhat close to what you want:

> The innerText property of the HTMLElement interface represents the "rendered" text content of a node and its descendants.
>
> As a getter, it approximates the text the user would get if they highlighted the contents of the element with the cursor and then copied it to the clipboard.
>
> > Note: innerText is easily confused with Node.textContent, but there are important differences between the two. Basically, innerText is aware of the rendered appearance of text, while textContent is not.

For the vast majority of DOM operations, `textContent` or `innerHTML` should be preferred, but this is one of the few times `innerText` could be warranted.

Comment: `innerText` won't have any of the layout. If you get the innerText of a table, you won't see the rows and columns.

Comment: Go into the console on this SO question and look at `document.querySelector(".sidebar-related").innerText`. The DIVs that are laid out side by side have newlines between them.

Comment: I just implemented `innerText` and it most surely preserves table layout marvelously as reported. There is a minor mystery in that for tables in a table the inner tables have layout well presevred and the outer table loses it (serializes the cells). None of which precludes the possible existence of a JS library which attempts to replicate what Lynx and ELinks do either, making this a valid question (as there are far more JS libraries out there than anyone can maintain an overview of).